# Getting wrong result while looking for avro files inside a HDFS directory

Tags: linux, hdfs

I would like to check if there is one or more avro files available inside a HDFS location

```
[cloudera@client01 scripts]$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05

Found 11 items
-rw-rw----   2 cloudera cloudera          0 2017-04-24 13:57 /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/_SUCCESS
-rw-rw----   2 cloudera cloudera     781714 2017-04-24 13:56 /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/part-r-00000-7e1d4e4e-9166-4744-b73b-095a7cc0e090.avro
-rw-rw----   2 cloudera cloudera     782132 2017-04-24 13:56 /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/part-r-00001-7e1d4e4e-9166-4744-b73b-095a7cc0e090.avro
-rw-rw----   2 cloudera cloudera     782467 2017-04-24 13:56 /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/part-r-00002-7e1d4e4e-9166-4744-b73b-095a7cc0e090.avro
-rw-rw----   2 cloudera cloudera     785117 2017-04-24 13:56 /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/part-r-00003-7e1d4e4e-9166-4744-b73b-095a7cc0e090.avro
```

But when i apply the below hdfs command i get nothing.

```
[cloudera@client01 scripts]$  hdfs dfs -ls /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/* | grep "part*.avro"
[cloudera@client01 scripts]$ echo $?
1
[cloudera@client01 scripts]$  hdfs dfs -ls /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/ | grep "part*.avro"
[cloudera@client01 scripts]$ echo $?
1
```

I am expecting 0 to be printed as there are many avro files located inside the HDFS location.

Could someone help me on what went wrong on this above command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you would need `.*` to match zero or more characters between the filename pattern in `grep`.

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/ | grep "part.*\.avro"
```

Or, you can use `-test` if need only the exit code.

```
hdfs dfs -test -e /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2017-04-05/part*.avro
echo $?
0
```